# Redirect user to a specific route based on the referring route after login

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, routes

<strike>In the `AuthController.php` I have a function:</strike>

```
public function authenticated( \Illuminate\Http\Request $request, \App\User $user ) 
{
    return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
}
```

I have login popup on every page so if the user logins from a page: `/demo-page` and logins, they will be redirected back to the same page(`/demo-page`) after login.
This works absolutely as expected. No problem here.

**My Question:** How can I redirect user to specific pages based on their current route from which the login was invoked.

Logic something like this:

```
if referring route('indexpage'){
    redirect to route('homepage');
}
else any other route other than index page{
    return redirect()-> to previous url
}
```

So previously I was looking at my `AuthController` file. But I forgot that I had changed the `LoginController` for the redirect

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->redirectTo = url()->previous(); //Redirect the user to previous page after login
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');

    }
```

**What I need to do:**

Suppose there are 3 routes. A, B and C

First the user lands on page **A**
If he logins there he have to be redirected to page **B**.

If the user is on page **B** and he logins there, he have to be redirected back to page **B**.

If the user is on page **C** and he logins there, he have to be redirected back to page **C**.

Note: the login is a common form on header of every page.

**What's currently working?**

With `return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());` this, 
the user from A is redirect to A, 
B to B 
and 
C to C.

Comment: I think, `URL::previous()` is what you are looking for, though not sure.

Comment: `return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());` this works for me getting the previous page. But I need to check if the user comes from the index page and redirect them to a particular page. and for other routes they need to be redirected to the previous page (As i have mentioned in the example code above)

Comment: @MilanChheda please check the question again. I have added more explanation to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
public function authenticated(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request, \App\User $user)
{
    if ($to = $request->input('redirect_route')) {
        $to = URL::route($to);
    }

    $to = $to ?: $this->redirectPath();

    return redirect()->intended(
        $to
    );
}
```

Read the API [here](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.html).

Comment: Thank you for you answer, But your method is same as doing this `return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());` Both works the same. This is working for me but I need to check from there the user is coming and if a user comes from a specifc page, I need to redirect them to a particular page.

Comment: You need custom input within your form. Check the updated answer.

Comment: I am not taking any input from the user. I guess you have not understood my question. Or may be I have failed to explain my issue :(

Comment: Please check the question again, I have added more explanation at the end.

Answer (score -1):

What you can do on the page where you restrict access to autorised users, use this code to set a url paramater called accesscheck:

```
$restrictGoTo = "login.php";
if (!((isset($_SESSION['Username'])) && 
(isAuthorized("",$authorizedUsers, $_SESSION['Username'], 
$_SESSION['UserGroup'])))) {   

  $qsChar = "?";
  $referrer = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
  if (strpos($restrictGoTo, "?")) $qsChar = "&";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) && strlen($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) > 
  0) 
  $referrer .= "?" . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  $restrictGoTo = $restrictGoTo. $qsChar . "accesscheck=" . 
  urlencode($referrer);
  header("Location: ". $restrictGoTo); 
}
```

And then on your login page. First thing you need to do is check if the url parameter accesscheck is present. It it is, redirect to the page after login, otherwise, go to the page specified.

```
if (isset($_GET['accesscheck'])) {
  $_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = $_GET['accesscheck'];
}


//run your login script and if the user is authenticated proceed to the 
previous url or the success page:

    $redirectLoginSuccess = "yourpage.php";
  if (isset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']) && true) {
      $redirectLoginSuccess = $_SESSION['PrevUrl']; 
    }
    header("Location: " . $MM_redirectLoginSuccess );
  }
```

This works even if you use parameters in your url's